# How to iterate over table for getting values of checkbox with checked state?

Tags: jquery, html-table, iteration

I have to access and get the values of rows with input checked state.

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr> <th>#</th> <th>Value 1</th> <th>Value 2</th> <th>Value 3</th> </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><input type='checkbox' name='1'></td> <td>1</td> <td>1</td> <td>1 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type='checkbox' name='2'></td> <td>2</td> <td>2</td> <td>2 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type='checkbox' name='3'></td> <td>3</td> <td>3</td> <td>3 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type='checkbox' name='4'></td> <td>4</td> <td>4</td> <td>4 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Suppose I checked the `checkbox 1 and 2` the first two line, I try to access just the values of these rows.

What is happening: or the values of all rows is being accessed or When I selected 2 rows just only one is showed.

```
$("table tbody tr input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
        console.log($("table tbody tr").html());
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.closest()` along with `$(this)`

```
$("table tbody tr input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
   console.log($(this).closest("tr").html());
});
```

Working sample:-

```js
$("table tbody tr input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
   console.log($(this).closest("tr").html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Value 1</th>
      <th>Value 2</th>
      <th>Value 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='1' checked></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='2' checked></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='3'></td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='4'></td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

***Or You need to use*** `.parents()` along with `$(this)`

```
$("table tbody tr input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
   console.log($(this).parents("tr").html());
});
```

Working sample:-

```js
$("table tbody tr input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
   console.log($(this).parents("tr").html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Value 1</th>
      <th>Value 2</th>
      <th>Value 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='1' checked></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='2' checked></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='3'></td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='4'></td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it possible to save this values in array and send to another page ?

Comment: @ThiagoL  yes. But for that you have to ask new question. It's hard to tell here. you can create an array object, iterate over each checked tr and get each td values . assign those values to array object and send it to another page via ajax request